# Display custom meta box in my template file

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, metabox, page-template

Need help displaying my custom meta boxes on a template file.

Following a [tutorial](http://wpshed.com/create-custom-meta-box-easy-way/)

Here's the code from my functions.php:

```
function get_custom_field( $value ) {
global $post;

$custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $value, true );
if ( !empty( $custom_field ) )
    return is_array( $custom_field ) ? stripslashes_deep( $custom_field ) : stripslashes( wp_kses_decode_entities( $custom_field ) );

    return false; 
}

// Register the Metabox
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box', __( 'Candidate Information', 'textdomain' ), 'meta_box_output', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box' );


// Output the Metabox
function meta_box_output( $post ) {
    // create a nonce field
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="textfield"><?php _e( 'Riding' ); ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="<?php echo get_custom_field( 'textfield' ); ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
<?php
}


// Save the Metabox values
function meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
    // Stop the script when doing autosave
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // Verify the nonce. If insn't there, stop the script
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // Stop the script if the user does not have edit permissions
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Save the textfield
    if( isset( $_POST['textfield'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'textfield', esc_attr( $_POST['textfield'] ) );

    }

 add_action( 'save_post', 'meta_box_save' );`
```

And what I've used to call the meta box from within the loop on my 'content-page.php' file.

```
<?php get_custom_field('textfield') ?>
```

I'm new to this — it's my first experience with custom meta boxes — and I'm sure I'm making a simple error.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, in part thanks to The Sufi's comment. I had:

```
<?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'textfield', true); ?>
```

Should have been

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'textfield', true); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'textfield', true )` inside the loop

Comment: Still no luck. :/ Edited my post above to show more code.

Comment: Please try to provide a more complete answer. This is really not more than a comment.